# Where do you typically declare and define functions outside a class in c++?

Tags: c++, function, header-files

I've been studying C++ for a little while now and want to start getting into actual application/software development. The problem is I'm having a hard time figuring out some of the more practical aspects of how to exactly setup a project. My question today is if I have a function that is not being declared and defined in a standard class structure, where exactly should I, or is it most common to, declare and define it? Most tutorials you watch will declare a function in main.cpp, above main() and then define it below main() but I assume that is just for teaching purposes and not real world application. Should you just create function header and source files just as you would with classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have the main cpp file along with separate header/source files for your own functions. Something like this:

/main.cpp

```
#include "myFunctions.h"

int main(){

    printSum(5, 5);
    return 0;    
}
```

/myFunctions.h

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H

void printSum(int, int);

#endif
```

/myFunctions.cpp

```
#include "myFunctions.h"

void printSum(int num1, int num2){

    cout << num1 + num2 << "\n"

}
```

Comment: `void main` is not standard.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to declare (prototype) the function in a .h file, and then implement it in a .cpp file. Example:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    // use the functions
    printf("%f, %f", add(10, 10), sub(64, 2.8));
}
```

`header.h`:

```
double add(double, double);       // function declarations
double sub(double, double);
```

`header.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"
double add(double a, double b)    // function implementations
{
    return a + b;
}
double sub(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Free Functions

For **free functions** the following scheme is the most common:

1. Put the definition of the function in a .cpp file.
2. Declare the function in a header.

> [Note: In C++ there's no need for the `extern` before a
>   function declaration because by default all functions have external
>   linkage. However, I  use it to emphasize that this is a declaration of
>   an externally defined function.]

For example if you have a free function named `int foo()`
in the .cpp file you put its definition:

```
int foo() {
  // does what ever...
}
```

And then in the header file (e.g., `.hpp` or `.h`) you put the declaration:

```
int foo();
```

### Member Functions

For **member functions** the typical scheme is:

1. Put `class` definition in a header file (e.g, `.hpp` or `.h`).
2. Put member function definitions in a `.cpp` file.

> [Note: Mind however, that there's the following difference between
>   defining a member function in its `class` body and definining it
>   elsewhere. In the first case the member function is declared
>   `inline`.]

For example if you have a `class Bar` that has a member function `int baz()`:

You would put the class definition in a header file:

```
class Bar {
  public:
  int baz();
};
```

And the the definition of the member function in its respective .cpp file:

```
int Bar::baz() {
  // do what ever...
}
```

> [Note: These rules are not typical and putting a function definition
>   above or below `main` is perfectly fine.]

Comment: I have never put `extern` on a free function prototype.

Comment: @NeilKirk wow, I'm impressed. Then you wouldn't mind explaining what is wrong with `extern`.

Comment: I don't know because I don't know why it is even there.

Comment: @NeilKirk In C++ there's no need for the `extern` before a function declaration because by default all functions have external linkage. However, It can be used to emphasize that this is a declaration of an externally defined function. The inclussion of `extern` or not is subjective and consequently the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @101010 C++ has a long history, and anything that contradicts it looks weird and may be confusing. Many people won't realise that you used a keyword just to emphasize the default. So your intention (make something clear) may lead to the exact opposite (people who read code are now confused).

Comment: @anatolyg I believe that this is primarily opinion based. In any case I include in the answer a note to emphasize that `extern` can be omitted and inclusion of it is a choice of mine. Really, I don't understand the reason for the down-votes.

Comment: I downvoted because of the unneeded `extern` and the unneeded info on how to declare/define member functions, and the unneeded vague reference to `inline`.

Comment: @anatolyg fair enough, seems you have your issues. **I removed the "unneeded" `extern`.**  Member functions are put as a bonus because in the OP the wording "I have a function that is not being declared and defined in a standard class structure" sounds to me unclear to whether it means free functions or member functions. IMHO, you down-vote a perfectly valid answer.